Rust Tetra Fails to Compile on MacOS
I've been trying to make a window show up with Rust so I can hopefully be able to make GUI applications in it (for fun). I've tried many engines but winit fails to compile on all of them so I decided to use Tetra. For some reason, it gives this incomprehensible error message when I try cargo run.
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: env -u IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET LC_ALL="C" PATH="/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/java/bin:/Users/synnove/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/synnove/.cargo/bin" VSLANG="1033" ZERO_AR_DATE="1" "cc" "-arch" "arm64" "/var/folders/3d/krsrjstj3d1br5cc6w6294gw0000gn/T/rustcNz0oF8/symbols.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.13s2nx2y1aogk6xi.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.1bp8u8xoi76cpcx7.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.1jf22wydw5rvhgs7.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.2q9wyz870mkaurt2.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.2rxpugni1couu884.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.3lhd3dnyesqpq3ux.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.3vdeulp11prisegd.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.4f0gndbut8v2dnqt.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.czl3kdx2g5xbw39.rcgu.o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55.3j5y4c4wuykjsbo2.rcgu.o" "-L" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libtetra-3c7d1f5b61dbf36e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsdl2-f8eb7977d028c913.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsdl2_sys-04758d37576982c3.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libglow-d7661477c1fda245.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libvek-6ad3c367bb866b15.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libapprox-1b7267597777bc0e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libnum_integer-94ddead0f4245ae5.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libab_glyph-7592102993ead52b.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libowned_ttf_parser-2f18063d7509c67f.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libttf_parser-4c5af52a3cb0437e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libab_glyph_rasterizer-aad8ef9259fa376e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libxi_unicode-ba24d6b53f2dc9b9.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libhashbrown-f91ad68c9ca45fd4.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libahash-5be66c130c836b93.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libonce_cell-d7962483dcb6d815.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libzerocopy-a9311f045af6d2bf.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libhalf-15a26884c48fc4bd.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblyon_tessellation-0d93558cf149fabc.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libfloat_next_after-6ed12b612a262ee3.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblyon_path-88d85dbc4e5f7fc1.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblyon_geom-d7a0dba6328f020b.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libeuclid-75ea498c4cfa6148.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libimage-b8b07941f16a1722.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libpng-4eedf83b2a3cc6cc.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libflate2-d802a6ad49645ea6.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libminiz_oxide-34aaf8243af00421.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libfdeflate-1c4d4bfd02333637.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsimd_adler32-77874f5dd94fab84.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcrc32fast-1616cecfeb0632ef.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libjpeg_decoder-3fab0d3379aa5471.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/librayon-3a526a9f21a5b57f.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/librayon_core-3540037264c7097b.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcrossbeam_deque-fe7f05a2f8cd0633.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcrossbeam_epoch-506f14449e8e1030.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcrossbeam_utils-0755ad59bf94eb3a.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libeither-7319c60b6e691d37.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libgif-307361321988968d.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcolor_quant-1b94d26f5b60eb38.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libweezl-b2b92f18ea4fa6e4.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libnum_traits-cb2a9407aff222c1.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/librodio-3ff829ff8fb52011.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libhound-af7672274031b7a4.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblewton-a5810bc3894af3df.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libogg-8cdb014b614c478b.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libtinyvec-8e1d44c6724d287a.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libtinyvec_macros-bec34d36023eb186.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libbyteorder-17a042d75ea328ea.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsymphonia-d4d221bbffa62842.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsymphonia_metadata-b8dd37f870301d7c.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libencoding_rs-02c43333b2165203.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcfg_if-f439f36af162daee.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsymphonia_bundle_mp3-a1c3a4b6e21af91e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libsymphonia_core-ff6d13c84b3eec49.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libbytemuck-34dee944aee6f2d2.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblog-f96ae2c9e0663462.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblazy_static-a73ed2ea0840451f.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libarrayvec-0fc60f9efdd0d5c6.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcpal-2cad72c3252362a8.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libmach2-d888b7701cdf3d51.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/liblibc-4034a1b9d7117f91.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libdasp_sample-00493d6c25b3db97.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcoreaudio-1bb9b30075819a1e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcoreaudio_sys-33f9b3c3cf25a401.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libcore_foundation_sys-ff2061a3c8a4e7db.rlib" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-d894f227a92c4677.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-b0083070c892a1db.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libpanic_unwind-8282820217d7b362.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libobject-f163e9d1987a8318.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libmemchr-350512940f04084a.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libaddr2line-e19e4ea986b9addc.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libgimli-363744fff3c4e7ba.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_demangle-e1d006f163566466.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd_detect-dea09910a3b22702.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libhashbrown-4802352fcc77de56.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-e71c86d9086176a7.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libminiz_oxide-6d82e7a8c3f5e2c7.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libadler-e66d24d044cc2029.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-46eaa7bd445cb528.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcfg_if-3c8a48285a1e7255.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-50e20e60add24734.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-edb678dd3e28691a.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-3b6c10a2acaa607f.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-2447397acf63b01e.rlib" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcompiler_builtins-5816c590a0da89c2.rlib" "-lSDL2" "-liconv" "-framework" "AudioUnit" "-framework" "CoreAudio" "-framework" "CoreFoundation" "-lSystem" "-lc" "-lm" "-L" "/Users/synnove/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "-o" "/Users/synnove/Desktop/snake/target/debug/deps/snake-e43a0c21ccf81e55" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: ld: library not found for -lSDL2
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: could not compile `snake` (bin "snake") due to previous error

Apple M1 chip if that helps, not sure what happened. I've tried copying my source code into a new directory and running there instead, but get the same error message. Any help would be appreciated.

I would recommend the winit crate for creating Windows. However if you're set on this path, the actual issue is that you haven't told the linker where to find the SDL library.

Thanks! How would I do that? I've tried installing SDL2 with brew but it still fails.

I'd ask the tetra devs, but they appear unresponsive. Depending on how much fun you really want to have, I would look into writing your game/whatever using wgpu and winit. Or there is, of course, Bevy.

Tetra dev here - have you followed the steps from the install guide with regards to setting LIBRARY_PATH to include the Homebrew lib directory? I have heard that newer Macs/Homebrew installs have issues without that.

@JoeClay did that and tried again, same error comes up. thanks though
